# Poduction Order Error

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

when I start the production order  http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=650344311.png

I get an error http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=780294952.png

I did not understand the error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is:

> Period for 28/03/2015 does not exists.

It means that some ledger posting is needed, but no ledger period for the date exists.

Resolution: [create a new fiscal year](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axinthefield/archive/2011/06/15/dynamics-ax-2009-financials-year-end-process.aspx)